# Mongodb or ElasticSearch: Finding available prefixes for a string field in a collection

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, prefix

Let's say I have a mongodb/elasticsearch user collection with a username field. Now I have some usernames inserted into the collection:

```
ABRAHAM
ADOLF
ADAM
ALFRED
ALBA
ARDUINO
```

What I want to find out is the inserted unique username prefixes given a certain length. So for length 2 the result should be:

```
AB
AD
AL
AR
```

Though it should be straight forward for a prefix index to accumulate a result like this. Does mongodb/elasticsearch provide any APIs to do something like this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `Elasticsearch` has this kind of api. You can try

```
GET /index/_search
{
    "aggs":{
        "duplicateCount":{
            "terms":{
                "script" : {
                    "inline": "doc.username.value.substring(0, prefixLength)",
                    "params": {
                        "prefixLength": 2
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can tune the `prefixLength` parameter. This will give you the result with the unique `username` of prefix length `prefixLength`.